# "Hot reload on save" not working on my Android Studio 3.5.3

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, hot-reload

I have a flutter project that I created from Android Studio. But when I make some changes and hit `Ctrl + S` for saving, `Hot reload` isn't working even though I have checked the checkbox `Hot Reload on Save` from preferences. However this was working fine previously. In between something messed up and now it isn't. Now I see when I run a project the `yellow lightening icon for hot reload` on Android Studio menu itself stays disabled.

Below is the log from my Run Console:

```
Launching lib\main.dart on Redmi 8 in debug mode...
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...
√ Built build\app\outputs\apk\debug\app-debug.apk.
Installing build\app\outputs\apk\app.apk...
This is taking longer than expected...
```

And here is the `flutter doctor` summery:

```
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.7, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393], locale en-US)

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.1)
[√] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[√] Proxy Configuration
[√] Connected device (1 available)
```

• No issues found!

Has anyone faced this issue before? Any solutions?

Comment: I would do the following, `flutter clean`. Then in android studio `File -> Invalidate Cacahes/Restart -> Invalidate and Restart`. Once restarted it might work.

Comment: @AbhilashChandran Tried this, but still not working

Comment: Can you provide the `flutter doctor` summary. I usually face some issues like this when my android studio updates or the underlying android itself updates.

Comment: Updated. Please check. It says no issues found.

Comment: Can you try Ctrl+\

Comment: @rstrelba, have tried this already, no result

Comment: Seriously, n one in the world has faced this issue other than me :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I fixed it. The issue was with the proxy settings. I had the environment variable `NO_PROXY` set on my machine as `127.0.0.1;localhost` instead of `127.0.0.1,localhost` (Notice the semi-colon instead of the coma). The local host addresses with a semi-colon seems like a value the flutter SDK doesn't understand as a valid `NO_PROXY` address which was causing my issue. Once I changed the `semi-colon` to `coma` it worked like a charm.

**How did I figure it out?**

From my Run Console I could see it saying `This is taking longer than expected...` which seemed abnormal and with little google search I found that is already a well know issue and people have fixed it. See [this github forum question](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/28702). There it is advised to keep the proxy addresses with a coma and not with a semi-colon. And that's it.

Comment: Where do you change the NO_PROXY environment variable?

Comment: @EderSavillon You can change this in the environment variables of the operating system. If it is not there then you can create it newly

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me, after I made some changes and nothing was reflected on save after make changes to code:

Press `ctrl + s` to save. Then press `r` for hot reload, in order to have changes reflect on the emulator.

In Flutter, `r` tells Dart Virtual Machine to `recompile`, `reload` and then `reassembly`.